# Does Orchard CMS have asynchronous drivers?

Tags: asynchronous, orchardcms

Is there an `AsyncDriver` object in Orchard that allows me to achieve with widgets what an `AsyncController` can do with regular MVC actions?

What would be involved in making one if not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope and actually adding one would not provide any real benefits, while introducing more complexity. You can already do asynchronous stuff in drivers if you wish.

Driver cannot be directly compared to controller as there are multiple of them called during a single request and they need to be synchronized at some point anyway - to build the final display/editor view. That being said - having `AsyncDriver` won't add anything more than what you can easily achieve now.

Plus - we're gonna be on .NET 4.5 very soon, so you'd be able to do use `async`/`await` sugars inside drivers and anywhere else.

Comment: Wouldn't using async/await inside drivers require the signature of the methods on `ContentPartDriver` be changed to `protected async Task<DriverResult>`? Is that something that is coming down the line?

Comment: It would and that's not on the radar now. A lot of problems may arise then due to possible multi-threading - not every piece of code in Orchard is thread-safe. Not to mention it would be a major breaking change. You may still do async things inside your driver methods without the signature change.

Comment: Drivers execution is actually very fast as most of the time all logic is put in the delegate within the returned value, thus deferred till the final rendering happens. And that need to be sync anyway.

Comment: If you could provide some performance comparison values and it will show that async drivers perform better - we will consider going for it of course.